# Move navbar object

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Hello I would like to move my login and register button to the right but can't and it's driving me insane!

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/5.0.0-alpha2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<nav id="mainNavbar" class="navbar navbar-dark navbar-expand-md py-0 pr-0 fixed-top">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"></a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navLinks" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
      <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navLinks">
      <ul class="navbar-nav" id="navbarIt">
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">ABOUT</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="" class="nav-link">SHOP</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <img src="https://imgur.com/DPTdSkH.png" alt="" class="rotate penguin d-none d-lg-inline">
      <div class="d-flex flex-row-reverse">
        <button type=" button me-2" id="login" class="btn btn-outline-info mr-2 nav-link pt-0 mt-2 mb-2">Login</button>
        <button type="button me-2" id="register"
          class="btn btn-outline-success mr-2 nav-link pt-0 mt-2 mb-2">Register</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: Hi there, PLEASE add show some code through a code snippet. Otherwise you will get downvotes.

Comment: How will we figure out what is going on in your code, If we don't have the code? Plz, provide the complete code of the respective problem.

Comment: Bootstrap 5 documentation https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/ use class "justify-content-end" after class "nav".

Comment: @NathanielFlick that will make all my navbar to go to the right. I only want the login and register button

Comment: @TROLITO "text-end" class https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/text/

Comment: @NathanielFlick nop that doens't work